# VBA Form takes input and saves to Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Getting errors when I run a user form in VBA. Created a user form in VBA to take input for multiple test variables.  Would like to have user click 'CommandBUtton2' button and have data saved to a worksheet in Excel.  Need to be able to clear form after saving data in order to continue updating worksheet with new test data.
UserForm1 receives input and has a button that switches to UserForm2.  UserForm2 takes input and has a button to submit (which should save inputted data into excel worksheet..it should lol)
Module1 code:

```
' Code behind Module1 to store public values
Public myText1 As String
Public myText2 As String
Public myText3 As String
Public myText4 As String
Public myText5 As String
Public myText6 As String
Public myText7 As String
Public myText8 As String
Public myText9 As String
Public myText10 As String
Public myText11 As String
Public myText12 As String
Public myText13 As String
Public myText14 As String
Public myText15 As String
Public myText16 As String
Public myText17 As String
Public myText18 As String
Public myText19 As String
Public myText20 As String
Public myText21 As String
Public myText22 As String
Public myText23 As String
Public myText24 As String
Public myText25 As String
Public myText26 As String
Public myText27 As String
Public myText28 As String
Public myText29 As String
Public myText30 As String
Public myText31 As String
Public myText32 As String
Public myText33 As String
Public myText34 As String
Public myText35 As String
Public myText36 As String
Public myText37 As String
Public myText38 As String
Public myText39 As String
Public myText40 As String
Public myText41 As String
Public myText42 As String
Public myText43 As String
Public myText44 As String
Public myText45 As String
Public myText46 As String
Public myText47 As String
Public myText48 As String
Public myText49 As String
Public myText50 As String
Public myText51 As String
Public myText52 As String
Public myText53 As String
Public myText54 As String
Public myText55 As String
Public myText56 As String
Public myText57 As String
Public myText58 As String
Public myText59 As String
Public myText60 As String
Public myText61 As String
Public myText62 As String
Public myText63 As String
Public myText64 As String
Public myText65 As String
Public myText66 As String
Public myText67 As String
Public myText68 As String
Public myText69 As String
Public myText70 As String
Public AdditionalNotes As String

' Code behind Module1 to actually use the values
Public Sub PrintVals()
   'Assign a macro to the OK button
   Dim emptyRow As Long
  'Make Sheet2 Active
   Sheets(2).Activate
   'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
  'Export Data to worksheet
  Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = myText1
  Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = myText2
  Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = myText3
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = myText4
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = myText5
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = myText6
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = myText7
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = myText8
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = myText9
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = myText10
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = myText11
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = myText12
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = myText13
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = myText14
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = myText15
Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = myText16
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = myText60 
Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = myText17
Cells(emptyRow, 19).Value = myText61 
Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = myText18
Cells(emptyRow, 21).Value = myText62 
Cells(emptyRow, 22).Value = myText19
Cells(emptyRow, 23).Value = myText20
Cells(emptyRow, 24).Value = myText21
Cells(emptyRow, 25).Value = myText22
Cells(emptyRow, 26).Value = myText23
Cells(emptyRow, 27).Value = myText24
Cells(emptyRow, 28).Value = myText25
Cells(emptyRow, 29).Value = myText63 
Cells(emptyRow, 30).Value = myText26
Cells(emptyRow, 31).Value = myText64 
Cells(emptyRow, 32).Value = myText27
Cells(emptyRow, 33).Value = myText65 
Cells(emptyRow, 34).Value = myText28
Cells(emptyRow, 35).Value = myText29
Cells(emptyRow, 36).Value = myText30
Cells(emptyRow, 37).Value = myText31
Cells(emptyRow, 38).Value = myText32
Cells(emptyRow, 39).Value = myText33
Cells(emptyRow, 40).Value = myText34
Cells(emptyRow, 41).Value = myText66 
Cells(emptyRow, 42).Value = myText35
Cells(emptyRow, 43).Value = myText67 
Cells(emptyRow, 44).Value = myText36
Cells(emptyRow, 45).Value = myText37
Cells(emptyRow, 46).Value = myText38
Cells(emptyRow, 47).Value = myText68 
Cells(emptyRow, 48).Value = myText39
Cells(emptyRow, 49).Value = myText40
Cells(emptyRow, 50).Value = myText41
Cells(emptyRow, 51).Value = myText42
Cells(emptyRow, 52).Value = myText43
Cells(emptyRow, 53).Value = myText44
Cells(emptyRow, 54).Value = myText45
Cells(emptyRow, 55).Value = myText46
Cells(emptyRow, 56).Value = myText47
Cells(emptyRow, 57).Value = myText48
Cells(emptyRow, 58).Value = myText49
Cells(emptyRow, 59).Value = myText50
Cells(emptyRow, 60).Value = myText51
Cells(emptyRow, 61).Value = myText52
Cells(emptyRow, 62).Value = myText53
Cells(emptyRow, 63).Value = myText69 
Cells(emptyRow, 64).Value = myText54
Cells(emptyRow, 65).Value = myText55
Cells(emptyRow, 66).Value = myText56
Cells(emptyRow, 67).Value = myText57
Cells(emptyRow, 68).Value = myText70 
Cells(emptyRow, 69).Value = myText58
Cells(emptyRow, 70).Value = AdditionalNotes
```

End Sub

```
' Code behind Form1 Initialize text boxes
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize(UserForm1)
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""
TextBox6.Value = ""
TextBox7.Value = ""
TextBox8.Value = ""
TextBox9.Value = ""
TextBox10.Value = ""
TextBox11.Value = ""
TextBox12.Value = ""
TextBox13.Value = ""
TextBox14.Value = ""
TextBox15.Value = ""
TextBox16.Value = ""
TextBox17.Value = ""
TextBox18.Value = ""
TextBox19.Value = ""
TextBox20.Value = ""
TextBox21.Value = ""
TextBox22.Value = ""
TextBox23.Value = ""
TextBox24.Value = ""
TextBox25.Value = ""
TextBox26.Value = ""
TextBox27.Value = ""
TextBox28.Value = ""
TextBox29.Value = ""
TextBox30.Value = ""
TextBox31.Value = ""
TextBox33.Value = ""
TextBox34.Value = ""
TextBox35.Value = ""
TextBox36.Value = ""
TextBox37.Value = ""
TextBox38.Value = ""
TextBox39.Value = ""
TextBox40.Value = ""
TextBox41.Value = ""
TextBox42.Value = ""
TextBox43.Value = ""
TextBox44.Value = ""
TextBox45.Value = ""
TextBox46.Value = ""
TextBox47.Value = ""
TextBox48.Value = ""
TextBox49.Value = ""
TextBox50.Value = ""
TextBox51.Value = ""
TextBox52.Value = ""
TextBox53.Value = ""
TextBox54.Value = ""
TextBox55.Value = ""
TextBox56.Value = ""
TextBox57.Value = ""
TextBox58.Value = ""
TextBox59.Value = ""
'Good values
TextBox60.Value = "14" 
TextBox61.Value = "Responds" 
TextBox62.Value = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" 
TextBox63.Value = "< 0.005"
TextBox64.Value = "4.5" 
TextBox65.Value = "2" 
TextBox66.Value = "100" 
TextBox67.Value = "11-16" 
TextBox68.Value = "5" 
TextBox69.Value = "6" 
TextBox70.Value = "10-11" 
End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm2_Initialize(UserForm2)
'Empty Additional Notes
TextBoxAdditionalNotes.Value = ""
End Sub

' Code behind Form1 Set variables on module
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(UserForm1)
Module1.myText1 = TextBox1.Value
Module1.myText2 = TextBox2.Value
Module1.myText3 = TextBox3.Value
Module1.myText4 = TextBox4.Value
Module1.myText5 = TextBox5.Value
Module1.myText6 = TextBox6.Value
Module1.myText7 = TextBox7.Value
Module1.myText8 = TextBox8.Value
Module1.myText9 = TextBox9.Value
Module1.myText10 = TextBox10.Value
Module1.myText11 = TextBox11.Value
Module1.myText12 = TextBox12.Value
Module1.myText13 = TextBox13.Value
Module1.myText14 = TextBox14.Value
Module1.myText15 = TextBox15.Value
Module1.myText16 = TextBox16.Value
Module1.myText17 = TextBox17.Value
Module1.myText18 = TextBox18.Value
Module1.myText19 = TextBox19.Value
Module1.myText20 = TextBox20.Value
Module1.myText21 = TextBox21.Value
Module1.myText22 = TextBox22.Value
Module1.myText23 = TextBox23.Value
Module1.myText24 = TextBox24.Value
Module1.myText25 = TextBox25.Value
Module1.myText26 = TextBox26.Value
Module1.myText27 = TextBox27.Value
Module1.myText28 = TextBox28.Value
Module1.myText29 = TextBox29.Value
Module1.myText30 = TextBox30.Value
Module1.myText31 = TextBox31.Value
Module1.myText32 = TextBox32.Value
Module1.myText33 = TextBox33.Value
Module1.myText34 = TextBox34.Value
Module1.myText35 = TextBox35.Value
Module1.myText36 = TextBox36.Value
Module1.myText37 = TextBox37.Value
Module1.myText38 = TextBox38.Value
Module1.myText39 = TextBox39.Value
Module1.myText40 = TextBox40.Value
Module1.myText41 = TextBox41.Value
Module1.myText42 = TextBox42.Value
Module1.myText43 = TextBox43.Value
Module1.myText44 = TextBox44.Value
Module1.myText45 = TextBox45.Value
Module1.myText46 = TextBox46.Value
Module1.myText47 = TextBox47.Value
Module1.myText48 = TextBox48.Value
Module1.myText49 = TextBox49.Value
Module1.myText50 = TextBox50.Value
Module1.myText51 = TextBox51.Value
Module1.myText52 = TextBox52.Value
Module1.myText53 = TextBox53.Value
Module1.myText54 = TextBox54.Value
Module1.myText55 = TextBox55.Value
Module1.myText56 = TextBox56.Value
Module1.myText57 = TextBox57.Value
Module1.myText58 = TextBox58.Value
Module1.myText59 = TextBox59.Value
Module1.myText60 = TextBox60.Value
Module1.myText61 = TextBox61.Value
Module1.myText62 = TextBox62.Value
Module1.myText63 = TextBox63.Value
Module1.myText64 = TextBox64.Value
Module1.myText65 = TextBox65.Value
Module1.myText66 = TextBox66.Value
Module1.myText67 = TextBox67.Value
Module1.myText68 = TextBox68.Value
Module1.myText69 = TextBox69.Value
Module1.myText70 = TextBox70.Value
Module1.AdditionalNotes = TextBoxAdditionalNotes.Value

UserForm2.Show
End Sub

' Code behind Form2 only calls module function
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click(UserForm2)
 PrintVals
 End Sub
```

When I run UserForm1 object: No errors but clicking commandbutton1 doesnt bring up UserForm2

Any help solving is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried .. it shown in worksheet, but error in form_initialize on newCCAbutton click .. would be better you give a link to your file ..

Comment: Thanks for trying! Not sure how to add a link to file - is the code posted enough to follow along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public is very abnormal in VBA Forms.  Your controls, like a TextBox, can be seen publicly from other forms.  So for instance, UserForm1 can see the textbox value on UserForm2 and vice versa.  So the following works if textboxes exist in both forms cases:

```
' Is the button that launches the second form
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  UserForm2.TextBox2.Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
  UserForm2.TextBox3.Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
  UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Also, if no text boxes exist on UserForm2, UserForm2 should still be able to access the values directly from the text boxes in UserForm1 like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   'Assign a macro to the OK button
   Dim emptyRow As Long
   'Make Sheet2 Active
   Sheets(2).Activate
   'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
   'Export Data to worksheet  
   Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

But in many cases it is most useful to put your shared content on a Module instead.  This way the public variables will be directly visible to all other forms, modules etc.

```
' Code behinde Module1 to store public values
Public myText1 As String
Public myText2 As String

' Code behind Module1 to actually use the values
Public Sub PrintVals()
   'Assign a macro to the OK button
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    'Make Sheet2 Active
   Sheets(2).Activate
   'Determine emptyRow  
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
   'Export Data to worksheet
   Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = myText1
   Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = myText2
End Sub

' Code behind Form1 Initialize text boxes
Private Sub Form_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = "1234"
    TextBox2.Value = "ABC"
End Sub

End Sub

' Code behind Form1 Set variables on module
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Module1.myText1 = TextBox1.Value
   Module1.myText2 = TextBox2.Value
   UserForm2.Show
End Sub

' Code behind Form2 only calls module function
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  PrintVals
End Sub
```

[Edit after several posts]

Try starting a new excel file that doesn't have any of your current code.  Create two new forms.  Add just three textboxes onto UserForm1, and one command button onto both form 1 and form 2.  Start with just the code from my solution above.  And see if you can get that to work.  If it works, then we can try to figure out what's different between the code above and your code and remove those differences if you can, or you can just flesh out the working example until it has all the textboxes you need.  If it doesn't work then there may be something different between the excel versions or something fundamental like that.

My project window looks like this:

[image: project window]

So the possibly important thing here is that all my forms are part of one Book.  If your forms are in different books, we will have to modify the code to handle that.

Comment: Sorry, yes I have updated the code so that SetText is Public.  In fact, you can also make the variables themselves public and set them directly if you you don't want to use a method call with 20 or 30 variables.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help. However, I still am getting a compile error "method or data member not found" and highlights the Private sub commandbutton1_click() command.  Any thoughts on how to approach fixing?

Comment: did you ever get this to work?  I have updated with an example from an actual test case, and it was easier than I was making it.

Comment: Cool, i cleaned up form 1 code and only have Initialize() and CommandButton_Click() methods.  I still get the compile error and am not sure why. Updated the code above if you want to check out - Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer to show some options.  It turns out "Public" is not really public on VBA Forms, but it works on modules.

Comment: Awesome, I like the module approach. I'm still getting a run-time 424 error object required.  Error comes from the CommandButton1_Click() Module1.myText1 = TextBox1.Value     ----wondering the issue because myText1 was already declared as a public variable

Comment: When you are typing the code in the CommandButton1_Click() event, and you type Module1.  Does autocomplete show you myText1 as a variable at that point?  If so does using Module1.myText1 = Me.TextBox1.Value work any better?  If not, is the variable actually Public?

Comment: Yes, autocomplete shows option. There is a Compile Error 'invalid use of Me keyword' when typing Module1.myText1 = Me.TextBox1.Value.   The myText1 variable is Public

Comment: Got rid of the error by doing Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(UserForm1) and Private Sub CommandButton2_Click(UserForm2).  Now if only the UserForm2 would show after clicking the commandbutton1 while running it.. thanks for all your help!

Comment: UserForm2.Show doesn't work?  It worked for me in my demo.  Is there an error again?  Maybe in the Form2 initialize.  try clearing the existing Form2 initialize code and see what happens.

Comment: Didn't work. I updated code to get rid of any errors but I think messing with the initialize events screwed it up.  Without the UserForm1&2 inside () i got run-time error 424 object required

Comment: Thanks :D i copied your code above and am not able to show Form2 when i click CommandButton1 - same problem as the original code. This is how im running it: (1)while UserForm1 object is selected i click Run and then (2)enter in stuff into textboxes and (3)click CommandButton1. Nothing happens when i click it though. How are you running it?

Comment: I can start it by pressing play, like you said, but maybe the event isn't connected yet.  Just double click on the command button to force it to generate a method handler.  Then paste the code in the method that it creates automatically.

Comment: Ohhh your demo code worked after generating a method handler! Tried the same for my code but after clicking CommandButton1 (while running) i received 424 error object required 'Module1.myText32 = TextBox32.Value' under the Private sub commandbutton1_click() of the UserForm1 code

Comment: So it sounds like TextBox32 might not exist, or might not be named correctly somehow?  See if you get autocomplete to show up when you are typing TextBox32.Value like it does for the other text boxes.  If not see if you can delete TextBox32 and re-add it to the form.  Also, try simply commenting out that one line and seeing if the rest works.

Comment: Yay it worked! I somehow forgot to make a textbox32 lol. Thanks for all your help !